# Month name abbreviations / mallongigoj de nomoj de monatoj

Tags: abbreviations

In several languages, there are common abbreviations for the names of [months of the Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Gregorian_calendar&oldid=996210170#Months). E.g. in English:

---

En pluraj lingvoj estas mallongigoj por la nomoj de [monatoj de la Gregoria kalendaro](https://eo.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Gregoria_kalendaro&oldid=6872720#Monatoj). Ekz. en la angla:

| Full month name | Abbreviated name |
| --- | --- |
| January | Jan. |
| February | Feb. |
| March | Mar. |
| April | Apr. |
| May | May (sic) |
| June | Jun. |
| July | Jul. |
| August | Aug. |
| September | Sep. |
| October | Oct. |
| November | Nov. |
| December | Dec. |

Does Esperanto also have such a set of commonly understood abbreviations for Month names of the Gregorian calendar?

---

Ĉu ankaŭ Esperanto havas tian vast-komprenitan mallongigaron de nomoj de monatoj de la Gregoria kalendaro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latest version of the [Common Locale Data Repository](http://cldr.unicode.org/) (maintained by Unicode) lists the [following abbreviations for Esperanto](https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/blob/367b79b4a86a9cb12314158897d950268dc77b02/common/main/eo.xml#L586):

```
jan
feb
mar
apr
maj
jun
jul
aŭg
sep
okt
nov
dec
```

Those are the same being used by gnu glibc, for the locale `eo`, and by Mozilla and by any localizable program in Unix/Linux, though capitalization might change.

Comment: Would these abbreviations be used with a period after them, as the English ones, e.g. "Aŭg."?

Comment: Esperanto lacks precise rules for many typographical things, incl. use of full stop in abbreviations. A general rule observed by many seems to be omit the full stop if the last letter is included. Therefore _s-ro_ for _sinjoro_ but _ekz._ for _ekzemple_. By that logic those should have full stops, but I think that in table headers it hardly matters.

Answer (score 0):

There are languages where months are expressed in numbers especially in writing, so using abbreviations may not be the most optimal solution. The [ISO 8601 standard](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) defines a date format to be used in all international communication to avoid misunderstandings. For instance today is 2020-12-29.

The standard also defines a notation for months only, e.g. 2020-12 for this month. I would claim that in a tabular representation, where you were likely to abbreviate the month names, that numerical representation of the month is more clear.

Comment: I'm well aware of ISO 8601. (See e.g. [my answer to "Date Format with Formal Correspondence"](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/a/5388/1576).) In this question here however though, I'm interested in actual abbreviations, not in numerical representation of months.

Comment: I know that you know :-) My point is to think where you would use the abbreviated names. In running texts? No, use the non-abbreviated names. In some sort of tables? Yes, but wouldn't a month number be better there?

Comment: In general, I'd prefer abbreviations in tables where months occur independent of years (i.e., in the meaning of "every January" or "on average in January within the considered multi-year period"). Specifically, I'm / I was translating [some strings](https://www.transifex.com/threema-gmbh-1/threema-web/translate/#eo/threema-web/157162248?q=key%3Adate.month_short) in [Threema web](https://threema.ch/threema-web), where the English original already uses abbreviations and I'm not sure in what contexts they'll be used exactly.

Comment: Ok, I was thinking sales figures or something like that for specific months.